# HttpWebRequest making duplicate request?

Tags: c#, windows-services, httpwebrequest

I'm running my program as a windows service and I'm trying to send a HTTP request everytime the time elapsed(i've set to 1 minute). What I'm trying to do at the server side is just writing a value that it gets from the query string. The writing to file works but i noticed there is some duplicate values being sent?

```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart, this is another new build 016");

            timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(5000D);
            timer1.AutoReset = true;
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer1.Start();

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("This is after calling start method");
        }
        catch (Exception exxx)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(exxx.Data.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop."); 
    }

    private static void timer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        el.WriteEntry("The Elapsed event was raised at " + i);
        i++;// i  is initialized to 0

        request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/Test.php?test=" + i);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = 5000;


        try
        {
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), request);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException e1)
        {
            el.WriteEntry("Exception 1:" + e1.Message);
        }
        catch (System.Net.ProtocolViolationException e2)
        {
            el.WriteEntry("Exception 2:" + e2.Message);
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException e3)
        {
            el.WriteEntry("Exception 3:" + e3.Message);
        }
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private static void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        request.GetResponse().Close();
    }
```

What i noticed in my file is something like 1,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,1. I don't see anything wrong with my code. Is it possible that the HttpWebRequest is sending duplicate request?

Comment: By chance does it do this after stopping and restarting the service?Every time you start the service, you're subscribing to a new timer event, but you never unsubscribe if you were previously subscribed to another timer. Your OnStop should actually `Dispose` of the timer as it implements `IDisposable`. This would fix the problem if stop/start is your problem.

Comment: Nope i just let it run without starting or stopping the service. And I'm sure that the service didn't in between because i do log the stop event.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion code is correct.I think you are using i variable somewhere else also.
Try changing i to something else which is not so common

HttpWebRequest never sends same request duplicate request.

For an instance let us assume that HttpRequest are duplicated then output should be something like 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3.....

Comment: I've tried to change to a unique variable, still same problem. Also, i've logged the http request that i've sent out and I'm sure its unique. What gives? That means like you said, HttpWebRequest never send a duplicated request. Perhaps the webserver itself is reissuing the duplicate http request?